# How to create a column that depends on another created column in pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

In the following MWE, I'm trying to create one `on use` column based on the definition of another `on use` column. PGF generates an error in this case:

```
PGFPlots: reading {test1.dat}
PGFPlots: reading {test2.dat}

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `value__column_not_found' (in 'value
__column_not_found.*0.75').
```

Although the example (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136049/32374)) is trivial, I would like to keep my original data files separated, but show some of the results together, along with some simple calculations. Is there any way to create a column based on another created column in `pgfplotstable`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/lb/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{value}*0.75}
    },
}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.dat}
parameter
1
2
3
4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.dat}
value
0.00034
0.0053
0.07
0.0027
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{test1.dat}\parameter
\pgfplotstableread{test2.dat}\value
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={parameter, value, lb},
    columns/parameter/.style={
        column name={Parameter},
    },
    columns/value/.style={
        column name={Default Value},
    },
    create on use/value/.style={create col/copy column from table={\value}{value}},
    columns/lb/.style={column name={Lower Bound}}.
]\parameter
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to copy the column into the table outside the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` macro using the `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` macro. Any additional columns that are based on the copied column can then be added by the usual `create on use` option. Jake's answer to [an unrelated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67088/32374) put me on the right track.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.dat}
parameter
1
2
3
4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.dat}
value
0.00034
0.0053
0.07
0.0027
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{test1.dat}\parameter
\pgfplotstableread{test2.dat}\value
% This gets added
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\value}{value}]{value}{\parameter}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\thisrow{value}/\thisrow{parameter}}]{ub}{\parameter}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/lb/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{ub}*0.6}
    },
}
%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={parameter, value, lb, ub},
    columns/parameter/.style={
        column name={Parameter},
    },
    columns/value/.style={
        column name={Default Value},
    },
    columns/lb/.style={column name={Lower Bound}},
]\parameter
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe there is a \foreach option for this, at least using the \pgfkeys version.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't understand how a `\foreach` loop is relevant here... can you write an answer (if you have the time :-))?

Answer (score 1):

Going through the manual again, the \pgfplotstablemodifyeachcolumnelemen command doesn't seem any more useful than "create col/expr=".  But the "set list" approach has some advantages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\def\parameters{1,2,3,4}
\def\values{0.00034,0.0053,0.07,0.0027}
%demonstration of how to use \foreach:  expr={} is more elegant.
\def\ub{}
\foreach \i in \values {\pgfmathmultiply{1.25}{\i}%
  \ifx\ub\empty\global\edef\ub{\pgfmathresult}
  \else\global\edef\ub{\ub,\pgfmathresult}
  \fi}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/parameter/.style={create col/set list/.expanded={\parameters}}}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/value/.style={create col/set list/.expanded={\values}}}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/lb/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{value}*0.75}}}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/ub/.style={create col/set list/.expanded={\ub}}}

\pgfplotstablenew[columns={parameter,value,lb,ub}]{4}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={parameter, value, lb, ub},
    columns/parameter/.style={
        column name={Parameter},
    },
    columns/value/.style={
        column name={Default Value},
    },
    columns/lb/.style={column name={Lower Bound}},
    columns/ub/.style={column name={Upper Bound}},
]\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't see how this answers the question... the macros `\parameter` and `\value` are `\def`fed, not read using `\pgfplotstableread`... is there a way to assign a column to a macro? My brief look at the manual didn't turn up anything.

Comment: You can copy a column to a macro using a loop similar to the one shown but using \pgfplotstablegetelem.  But if you are reading the data from a table (as opposed to creating it in latex), it doesn't really gain you much.